# Why does OMAC2 exist?

Tags: mac, cmac

The specification for OMAC has the following to say about OMAC2:

> For OMAC2, we adopted u<sup>−1</sup> instead of u<sup>2</sup> as Cst<sub>2</sub>. It requires one right shift to compute L· u<sup>−1</sup> instead of one left shift to compute (L· u)· u. This would allow to compute both L · u and L · u<sup>−1</sup> from L simultaneously if both left shift and right shift are available (for example, the underlying block cipher uses both shifts).

This seems to imply that the only (?) purpose of OMAC2 is to be more efficient to calculate if you're operating on hardware that implements both a left *and* a right shift? (How luxurious! Oh wait, what hardware *doesn't* do that?)